# Red stain in the form of "crescent" on a display

Tags: display, hardware-failure, desktop-computer

I revealed a small problem with the monitor 27 "Lenovo ThinkVision S27Q-10 [61E8GAT1EU].

The problem is that on a dark background in the upper right half of the monitor (a little right of the middle), a red stain was noticeable in the shape of a crescent (the photos attached to handling). There is no light background of this stain.

I tried to "shake" pixels using JScreenFix Pixel Repair (instead of 10 minutes the test lasted 5 minutes), but it did not give anything completely no effect.

Overheating in any part of the monitor I did not notice, the mechanical impact on the screen did not turn out, the sources of superal electromagnetic radiation nearby too.

Can audio speakers influence this? Or maybe the problem with the output of the image can then be to blame the video card (i have no built-in GPU).

It is possible that this is a IPS defect, but these are just my guesses.

Can I try to eliminate the problem remotely, or will I need to appeal to the service?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I completely disconnected the monitor from the network overnight, changed the settings, reset to the factory settings - no effect.

Comment: The monitor has a hardware problem and needs to be replaced.

Comment: @John
The problem lies in the monitor itself, it's clear. And what could be the cause of such problems?

Comment: When I have seen this, there is a defect in the screen itself.

Comment: @John
This defect appeared two days after buying a PC. In addition to a clean system and drivers, I have not installed anything else.

Comment: I don't know in this case.

Comment: We cannot guess what may have caused something like this. It doesn't look like damage, so I'd just return the computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a screenshot using the operating system. If the stain is not in the image,
this verifies that the monitor itself has a problem.

Such a hardware problem means that some pixels are bad.
This kind of a problem is usually not repairable,
so I'm afraid you will in this case need to look for a new monitor
(or screen for a laptop).

Comment: I didn't even think about the screenshot. Or maybe this is due to the video card and the driver for it?

Comment: @dtn probably not: such an error would not create a mark like this

Comment: @dtn There could be a driver issue causing incorrect rendering and it would not show up on a screenshot, just like a screen malfunction. However, it is very unlikely to look like this. Another possible way of verifying is to try connecting the device to a different screen (i.e., an external monitor or even a TV should work just fine) and see if the issue persists. If it does, it's not a screen issue. If it doesn't, which seems far more likely given the pictures you provided, it is a screen issue.

Comment: @natiiix Can I try to connect a PC to a laptop via hdmi?

Comment: does not work that way - one does not simply connect HDMI that way and sources and sinks are different.  If you just bought it, it ought to be under warranty, and you should get it replaced as soon as possible.

Comment: @dtn I'm afraid that's not possible unless you just so happen to have a device called a capture card. I must agree with Journeyman Geek here. If it's still under warranty and you can spare it for a couple of weeks, you should send it for a repair/replacement. Regardless of the kind of the underlying issue, this doesn't seem like something that could possibly go away with time. Even if it's an older laptop that is no longer under warranty, it is often possible to get the screen replaced by someone who specializes in this kind of repairs. It will cost you, but hopefully less than a new laptop.

Comment: The monitor is under warranty, so I take it to a service center. I think they will solve the problem, and I also have a feeling that the defect is pretty commonplace.